# SBT scala monkey patch library

Tags: java, scala, sbt, monkeypatching

I want to replace a case class from a library with my custom class with more parameters.

I do not want to exclude anything from the library. What I'm doing is creating a class with same package name on my project but it is raising error on runtime.

Example:

- library: `mamilo.rosa.jar:/com/mamilo/rosa/CaseClassA.scala`
- my project: `src/scala/com/mamilo/rosa/CaseClassA.scala`

What I want to do is remove that class from library or replace it with my one but it still raising runtime error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mamilo.rosa.CaseClassA.<init>(Lscala/collection/Seq;...)
```

#### EDIT

I'm trying to add a new parameter to this case class: https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/searches/SearchDefinition.scala

Which will be used and converted to a HTTP request (that I will try to override too). What I want to do is add some changes on his library and when it becomes good I can submit a PR with some changes, but I'm doing it on my project that contains this library as dependency.

Comment: Can you provide more context? I've seen similar errors when a project has two dependencies that are (binary) incompatible, e.g. two different versions of the same library.

Comment: Done, I add more context (I think)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1) Add an `implicit class` conversion, e.g. `RichSearchDefinition`, which will allow you to use your own methods when the implicit conversions is in scope. This is known as the "enrich my library" (or sometimes "pimp my library") pattern. The code will look roughly like this:

```
object Implicits {
  implicit class RichSearchDefiniton(sd: SearchDefinition) {
    // Define methods here that you'd like to use on `SearchDefinition`
    def printSomething: Unit = println("This is an example of enriching a library.")
  }
}
```

Wherever you need this functionality, you can simply import the implicit conversion: `import mypackage.Implicits._`

2) Make changes to the library locally, change the version number to something like `0.0.1-LOCAL`, and use `sbt publishLocal` to publish a local copy of it. In your project, you can depend on this locally-published library. When you're satisfied that it works, you can submit a pull request with your change. One caveat here is that, if `elastic4s` is included transitively through another dependency, you'll have to [exclude](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies) it in your `build.sbt` file

Answer (score 0):

You could define an implicit conversion from their type to your type and vice-versa, something like this:

```
// All of their existing stuff
case class TheirType(a: Int, b: String)
def theirFunction(x: TheirType) = Unit

// Your new case class
case class YourType(a: Int, b: String, c: Boolean)
def yourFunction(yourType: YourType) = Unit

// Define the implicit functions to convert from one type to another (and back)
implicit def theirsToYours(t: TheirType): YourType = YourType(t.a, t.b, true /* You will need to supply some value here */)
implicit def yoursToTheirs(y: YourType): TheirType = TheirType(y.a, y.b)

// You can now pass your type to their functions and vice-versa
val y = YourType(10, "abc", false)
theirFunction(y)

val t = TheirType(99, "123")
yourFunction(t)
```

The drawback here is that you will need to decide on some default value for your new parameter, since their existing functions would have no way to create that value on their own.